# How to use the pen tool in pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

In Photoshop when I want to cut out part of a picture I can easily move along the edges with the pen tool and draw my curves - not so easy with Pixelmator. Especially the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does not do anything when clicking the handles here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the outline while having the pen selected and the shape will appear with red dots. This will allow you to move the handles.